# Reflect on TypeVar in Custom Generic Class method

Tags: python, generics, factory, typing

Consider the code bellow.

```py
>>> class A(typing.Generic[T]):
...     @classmethod
...     def foo(cls) -> None:
...         print(typing.get_args(cls))
...
>>> A[int].foo()
()
>>> typing.get_args(A[int])
(<class 'int'>,)
```

Is it possible to infer the concrete type stored in `T` in the `A.foo()` class method?

This is a rather generic (sic) example. A real-world use case would be to implement a generic constructor which calls `T` type's constructors or generic factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [open](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/629) issue on `typing` repo for this particular case.

Comment: That's unfortunate:( But thanks anyway!